# How to repeat same thread group after the thread group gets response in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

Here is my scenario:

I have one thread group call thread group A.

Inside thread group A, I have one Http request with POST.

I have set 10 as number of threads, ramp up period is 10 seconds.

Until I stop the test, I want to call the same thread group (or Http request) after getting reponse from HTTP request from the previous HTTP call.

So it looks like:

1. Start test
2. Call HTTP requet
3. Get response from HTTP request
4. repeat step 2,3 until I stop the test

The reason why I didn't use fixed time delay is because the reponse time for HTTP request is not fixed and I want to give a continuous load to my server.

---Edit---
[image: Case When I tried infinite loop]
[image]

Here is the case when I tried infinite loop. As you can see, the post requests are sent almost all at once and failed to get response.

I need my first POST request is sent, succeed, gets response then the new POST request is sent, succeed, gets reponse and continue one by one until I stop Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Just tick `Infinite` box next to "Loop Count" in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or set number of loops to `-1`

[image]

Then you can [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/test/result.jtl
```

and the test will run forever until you manually stop JMeter process.

The best way to stop a running test is invoking either [`shutdown.cmd`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/shutdown.cmd) or [`shutdown.sh`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/shutdown.sh) (depending on your operating system)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already done that, as you said it looped until I stopped, but it did not start the new call after the response is given. I kept start new tests, which wasn't my purpose

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, how do you know "it did not start the new call"? I can think of the situation that the "call" is "started" but there is no response. Hard to say anything without seeing [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) output with your command used for starting the test and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file (preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging))

Comment: I have added log and more detailed explanation about my desired situation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your "detailed explanation" is not detailed at all. I can see only the fact that the test is being stopped after 1 second of running which means that your statement regarding Thread Group setup is wrong.